# Email client that handles arbitrary addresses

Tags: email, email-client

I have a number of email accounts, including a Gmail account, a university alumni account (IMAP), a work account (Microsoft Exchange), and addresses at my personal domain.  In particular, for my personal domain, while I currently only use one address `me@example.com`, I intend to start using arbitrary addresses at the domain so I can classify email based on their `To` header.

I'm looking for an email client that can handle all of the above; in particular, I should be able to:

- One-click or shortcut key "Archive" action that places the email in an Archive folder, unless if sent to my personal domain, in which case it should place it in a folder based on the To header (i.e. and thus this needs to support arbitrary rules)
- Send email from any address at my personal domain, in addition to any of my other email addresses (i.e. if possible, a free-text From field would be ideal)

I should also obviously be able to send/receive email from my non-personal-domain accounts as normal as well as be able to use folders. Email threading, incidentally, is nice but not required. I should not that I don't use Gmail labels at all, so support for that is not required (although some existing emails have labels, so the client must not break on those).

Additional features that are all pluses but not required include:

- Email snoozing
- Proper integration of Drafts/Sent/Spam/Trash folders (I now have three different Sent folders in one of my accounts because I can't tell the current clients I use which one is which)
- Ability to import email archives
- Traditional delivery/read receipt support (not tracking pixels)
- Scheduling of outbound emails (e.g. send this in 6 hours)

There are also probably some other fancy-21st-century features I've forgotten that would be nice.

I am happy with either Mac or Windows desktop clients or web clients, and am willing to pay non-insane amounts of money.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the well-known **Thunderbird** is a good solution for these requirements. Thunderbird is Free Open-Source Software and available for Windows, OS X, Linux, BSD etc.

> One-click or shortcut key "Archive" action that places the email in an Archive folder, unless if sent to my personal domain, in which case it should place it in a folder based on the To header (i.e. and thus this needs to support arbitrary rules)

In Thunderbird you can create [mail filters](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/organize-your-messages-using-filters) with these rules. You can chose when they should be executed, of of these possibilities is "Archiving". You can archive a mail be either right-clicking -> Archive, add the button "Archive" to your menu or by pressing "a".

> Send email from any address at my personal domain, in addition to any of my other email addresses (i.e. if possible, a free-text From field would be ideal)

Is possible out-of-the-box in Tunderbird. Just click "Customize address" in the "From:" dropdown

> Email snoozing

I'm not aware of this feature in thunderbird. I usually use IMAP's tags to classify them.

Also, you can use the integrated Calendar for this.

> Proper integration of Drafts/Sent/Spam/Trash folders (I now have three different Sent folders in one of my accounts because I can't tell the current clients I use which one is which)

You can set these folders individually per account in the account settings.

> Ability to import email archives

Can be done, but the requirement is very unspecific.

> Traditional delivery/read receipt support (not tracking pixels)

Thunderbird does not load external content by default.
It also supports both responding to and requesting read receipts via mail.

> Scheduling of outbound emails (e.g. send this in 6 hours)

In the standard configuration you can send later but without defining a time (Mails are saved in the Outbox, can be used to write emails during offline time). With the Addon [Send Later](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/send-later-3/) you can additionally specify a time.